# Create save and return feature

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way to save a form that the user is filling in and then return to it later?

It would be good if the user can create a username/password/email to use to return to the form.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

It is not currently possible to save and resume.  However, this is definitely a feature we are planning to support, especially now that forms can be multi-page surveys.  Here is a link to this feature on our Idea Board: [Save & Resume](https://trello.com/c/Bk6swilY).  Please vote on this feature on our board!

We envision two levels of save and resume, one like the above which is just sending a link to an email address that supports editing a single entry without registering for an account, and another where your customers can register and then be able to view entries to forms they have previously submitted.  Support for this will require [Public User Profiles](https://trello.com/c/u5WcAYkd) which is definitely on our to-do list for 2015.

Comment: I hope this feature will be added this year as soon as possible! :)
Anyway, do you have a date when this will be done?

Comment: Support for Save & Resume is now live!  https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/save-resume