# Making Cognito form editable by submitter at later date

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I make a Cognito form that allows the submitter to be able to edit the form at a later date?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

Currently we do not offer the support to save a form before its submitted so that it can be edited at a later time. We are looking to add this feature in the future and you can follow our progress over on our Idea Board: [Save & Resume](https://trello.com/c/Bk6swilY).

A question similar to this was ask by another user, and was answered by another Cognito Forms developer Jamie T. You can find that users question and his answer at the following link:
[Create save and return feature](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/72620/create-save-and-return-feature)

Comment: Save & Resume was released on May 28th, and we are also now working to add support for sharing entries via secure links that will work post-submission as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the form, until you press the **Send form** button, it will remain non-published, and in your drive (you can close it, open it again, edit the questions, etc)

Comment: @pnuts totally, I get the point of the question. I just poset a quick workaround